# Hyperlink not getting displayed in Php mail

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to email a link thru PHPMail. Somehow link is showing as plain text in email.

I want that link should be clickable when received in email. Currently it is showing as plain code.

Below is the code, please help!

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['firstname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phoneno=$_POST['phoneno'];
$com=$_POST['comment'];

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
?>

<a href="hello.php?a=<?php echo $name; ?>&b=<?php echo $email; ?>&c=<?php echo $phoneno; ?>&d=<?php echo $com; ?>">Print Boss your receipt</a>

<?php
//$link="hello.php?a=$name&b=$email&c=$phoneno&d=$com";
$to = "ketanjoshi1993@gmail.com";
//$from = $email;
$subject = "send email in pdf format";
$message = "<a href='#'>test</a>";

$email = mail($to,$subject,$message);
if( $email == true )
{
    echo "sent";
}
else
{
    echo "not sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: Some say two, some say four, some even say three. But indenting 20 spaces is a first.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use your headers in your mail call:

`$email = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Answer (score 0):

So you forget to add the headers

try adding it as
`$email = mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);`

It will work

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the headers

You can do like this :

```
    $email = mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

If you don't pass the header parameter in PHP mail() function , default headers will be set & your will be treated as simple text body.